# Parallelism of window-functions in Spark 2

Tags: apache-spark, window-functions

I have a rather simple (but essential) question about Spark window functions (such as e.g. `lead, lag, count, sum, row_number` etc):

If a specify my window as `Window.partitionBy(lit(0))` (i.e. I need to run the window fucntion accross the entire dataframe), is the window aggregate function running in parallel, or are all records moved in one single tasks?

EDIT:

Especially for "rolling" operations (e.g. rolling average using something like `avg(...).Window.partitionBy(lit(0)).orderBy(...).rowsBetween(-10,10)`), this operation could very well be split up into different tasks even tough all data is in the same partition of the window because only 20 row are needed at once to compute the average

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define as `Window.partitionBy(lit(0))` or if you don't define `partitionBy` at all, then all of the `partitions` of a `dataframe` will be `collected` as one in one `executor` and that `executor` is going to perform the `aggregating` function on whole `dataframe`. So `parallelism` will not be preserved.

The collection is different than the `collect()` function as `collect()` function will collect all the `partitions` into `driver` node but `partitionBy` function will collect data to `executor` where the `partitions` are easy to be collected.

Comment: you think also "rolling" operations as e.g. rolling average is also not implemented in a distributed way (see me updated answer)?

Comment: Yes @RaphaelRoth, I think so. Because you are defining whole dataset as one partition. So they will be shuffled to accumulate in one executor.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan  1) So what about this default 200 partitions of a dataframe that I read about elsewhere? 2) So what about a time based nested correlated sub-query where you may not know how many time partitions? 3) Are buckets not important performance aspect as well?